# LWC Progress Ring: Unable to set ring content

Tags: lightning-web-components, progress-ring

Using `SLDS` you can set some content in a `Progress Ring`

```
<div class="slds-progress-ring slds-progress-ring_large">
   <div class="slds-progress-ring__progress" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0">
        <svg viewBox="-1 -1 2 2">
            <path class="slds-progress-ring__path" id="slds-progress-ring-path-323" d="M 1 0 A 1 1 0 0 0 1.00 -0.00 L 0 0"></path>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-progress-ring__content">4</div>
</div>
```

So the ring has a `4` in it:

[image]

But using the `LWC` implementation of `Progress Ring` does not seem to give you any way to set a value inside of `slds-progress-ring__content`

```
<lightning-progress-ring size="large" value="11">11</lightning-progress-ring>
```

Does not show the value of `11` in the ring, and having a `value` of 11 just causes the ring to be 11% complete:

[image]

If I inspect the `HTML` rendered using the LWC `lightning-progress-ring` it does create the div:

```
<div class="slds-progress-ring__content"></div>
```

But it is empty.

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-progress-ring/documentation) and [specification](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-progress-ring/specification) do not mention any way of achieving.

Is there any undocumented way of setting some content?

Comment: I don't think its possible with lightning-progress-ring, since its locked dom, we can't manipulate with text with css/JS :(

Answer (score 0):

`<lightning-progress-ring size="large" value="11"></lightning-progress-ring>`

The value 11 should be in the value attribute as documented in the link you have in the question

Regarding showing something like an alt attribute the component does not have that and it does not support slots.

Comment: The first part of your answer does not relate to my question. I know what the `value` property does. I've updated the question to make this clearer.